# HybridAuth Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, hybridauth

I installed HybridAuth 2.8 using composer and I'm trying to use it with CodeIgniter 3.

I created a library which is extending Hybrid_Auth.

```
class MY_HybridAuth extends Hybrid_Auth {

   function __construct($config = []) {
       $this->_CI =& get_instance();
       $this->_CI->load->helper('url');
       $config = $this->_CI->config->item('hybridauth');
       $config['base_url'] = base_url() . $config['base_url'];
       parent::__construct($config);
   }
}
```

**My controller** :

```
public function social($provider) {
    $provider = ucfirst($provider);
    log_message('debug', "controllers.Auth.social($provider)");
    // TODO Handle missing parameter properly
    if (!isset($provider)) redirect('login', 'location');
    try {
        if ($this->HybridAuth->is_provider_enabled($provider)) {
            $service = $this->HybridAuth->authenticate($provider);
            var_dump($service->getUserProfile());
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
}

public function endpoint() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['hauth_start']) || isset($_REQUEST['hauth_done'])) {
        Hybrid_Endpoint::process();
    }
}
```

**My problem is** :

When the user is redirected to `/login/social/endpoint?auth.start...`, HybridAuth appends the current url to the new one (`localhost/login/localhost/login/social/endpoint?auth.start...`).

HybridAuth is using `header("Location: $url")` to redirect the user.
I setted my `base_url` to `localhost`.
My HybridAuth endpoint is : `base_url() . /login/social/endpoint`, which is handled by the `endpoint` method in above controller.

May someone help ?

Comment: If not, set base url to `"http://localhost/"` instead of `"localhost"`. Pay attention to scheme and trailing slash ([docs](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L9)).

Comment: That was the trailing slash ... Thanks a lot !

Comment: You are welcome. Just follow docs as much as possible and you'll avoid errors like this one. #SOreadytohelp